# Query google trend using google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I need help with google BigQuery. Am using big query to query data from Google Trends. now I want to get data using a specific keyword example spiderman, and get the result in regions like CSV downloaded in google trend "interest over time". But google trend has this code only view 25 top-trending terms

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_trends.top_terms`
WHERE refresh_date = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I want to use same syntax to get data for a specific term/keyword.